# How to find the minimum of $c|1+x|^n+|1-x|^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, absolute-value

How to find the minimum of the 
\begin{align}
f(x)=c|1+x|^n+|1-x|^n
\end{align}
for $n \ge 1$ and $c > 0$.

If we take the derivative of $f(x)$ we get
\begin{align}
f'(x)=-c  {\rm sign}(1+x) |1+x|^{p-1} -  {\rm sign}(1-x) |1-x|^{p-1} 
\end{align}
but how do solve for $f'(x)=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest splitting your equation into multiple parts. Indeed we have
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} c(1 + x)^n + (x - 1)^n, \ x \in [1,\infty) \\
c(1 + x)^n + (1 - x)^n, \  x \in [-1,1) \\
c(-1)^n (1 + x)^n + (1 - x)^n, \ x \in (- \infty, -1)
\end{cases}$$
Now you may compute the derivative for each of these intervals separately and consider in which of the intervals $f$ attains its smallest value compared to the others!

Comment: Thanks. I got. Thank you for the suggestion.